# Why is TaskCanceledException thrown and does not always breaks into the debugger

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm digging into the `async-await` mechanism and observed the throwing of a `TaskCanceledException` that I can't explain yet.

In the sample below (self contained) I have the statement

```
await Task.Run(() => null);
```

I know that this statement on itself is useless but I isolated the issue, the real code has logic and returns null in some cases.

Why does this throw a `TaskCanceledException`? If I return an arbitrary number (5 in the below example) it does not throw.

Furthermore if I `await` the method the debugger of VS breaks but If I don't `await` it then only a message is written to the output window of VS.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testAsync = new TestAsync();

        // Exception thrown but the debugger does not step in. Only a message is logged to the output window
        testAsync.TestAsyncExceptionOnlyInTheOutputWindow();

        // Exception thrown and the debugger breaks
        testAsync.TestAsyncExceptionBreaksIntoTheDebugger();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal class TestAsync
{
    public async void TestAsyncExceptionOnlyInTheOutputWindow()
    {
         TestNullCase();
    }

    public async void TestAsyncExceptionBreaksIntoTheDebugger()
    {
        await TestNullCase();
    }

    private static async Task TestNullCase()
    {
        // This does not throw a TaskCanceledException
        await Task.Run(() => 5);

        // This does throw a TaskCanceledException
        await Task.Run(() => null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your TestAsyncExceptionOnlyInTheOutputWindow will continue to execute without waiting for TestNullCase to complete, because it is missing await. So likely, any exception is consumed, because the thread has no way of reporting it.

Comment: This might be an interesting bug in the Framework itself. For the time being, can you use Nullable<T> instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TaskCanceledException

The reason `Task.Run(() => null)` returns a canceled task rests in **overload resolution**. The compiler chooses `static Task Run(Func<Task> function)` and not `static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)` as one may expect. It acts as if you're calling an `async` delegate, which in this case you're not. That results in `Task.Run` "unwrapping" your return value (`null`) as a task which in turn would cancel the task.

The specific code responsible for that is in the [`ProcessInnerTask` private method in the `UnwrapPromise<TResult>` (inherits from `Task<TResult>`) class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#7ec49a100f240b06#references):

```
private void ProcessInnerTask(Task task)
{
    // If the inner task is null, the proxy should be canceled.
    if (task == null)
    {
        TrySetCanceled(default(CancellationToken));
        _state = STATE_DONE; // ... and record that we are done
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can easily tell the compiler not to do that by telling the compiler you are not returning a `Task`:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => (object)null); // Will not throw an exception. result will be null
```

### Exception Handling

The difference between the two methods is that in `TestAsyncExceptionOnlyInTheOutputWindow` you don't `await` the faulted task and so the exception stored in the task is never rethrown.

You can make the debugger break in both methods by checking the *thrown* column on *Common Language Runtime Exceptions* in your settings (Debug => Exceptions):

[image: Exceptions]

Answer (score 3):

It seems when you call Task.Run (()=> null) it will choose

```
 public static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> function)
```

overload of function and when you return null the result task proxy is somehow faulty, if you use

```
Task.Run (()=> (object)null)
```

Instead it will pick the right overload

```
Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
```

like your int sample Task.Run(() => 5); and it wont throw exception.

But what actually

```
public static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> function)
```

overload mean I could not find the answer.

> ```
>  public static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> function)
> ```
>
> method is used by language compilers to support the async and await
>   keywords. It is not intended to be called directly from user code

.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the `Func<T>` with a method, it passes.

```
    private static async Task TestNullCase()
    {
        // This does not throw a TaskCanceledException
        await Task.Run(() => 5);

        // This does throw a TaskCanceledException
        await Task.Run(() => GetNull());
    }

    private static object GetNull()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

After letting ReSharper convert both lambdas to variables:

```
    private static async Task TestNullCase()
    {
        // This does not throw a TaskCanceledException
        Func<int> func = () => 5;
        await Task.Run(func);

        // This does throw a TaskCanceledException
        Func<Task> function = () => null;
        await Task.Run(function);
    }
```

So, the second form is incorrectly interpreted as `Func<Task>` instead of your intent, which I believe is `Func<object>`. And because the Task passed in is null, and because you can't execute a null, you get a `TaskCanceledException`. If you change the variable type to `Func<object>` it works without any additional changes.

Comment: Thanks for the clean explanation "can't execute a null"