# Under what circumstances will awaiting a cancelled task throw TaskCanceledException?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm used to being able to perform an asynchronous pattern when handling cancellation of asynchronous operations:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using(cancellationToken.Register(handler.Stop))
    {
        try
        {
            await handler.HandleAsync();
        }
        catch(HandlerStoppedException ex)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The method calls an asynchronous component which exposes some kind of cancel mechanism. The cancellation token sets up a callback to invoke the cancel mechanism when the token signals cancellation is requested.

I can call this method in my tests to exercise its function within a timeout.

```
async Task TestInvoke()
{
    using (var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    {
        try
        {
            await InvokeAsync(timeout.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCancelledException ex)
        {
            if (ex.CancellationToken == timeout.Token)
            {
                throw new TimeoutException(
                    "Operation failed to complete in the allowed time.", ex);
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is that throwing `OperationCanceledException` within an `async` method will cause the `Task` returned by the method to transition to the "Canceled" state. I then expect any attempts to await this cancelled task should throw a `TaskCanceledException`.

In my current scenario (code very similar to above) I instead get an `OperationCanceledException` when I await the task. If I examine the state of the task, I can see it is in a "Canceled" state and has no exception associated with it.

More curiously, if I call `Wait()` on the task, it throws an `AggregateException` containing the expected `TaskCanceledException` instead.

Under what circumstances will awaiting a cancelled task throw `OperationCanceledException` instead of the more typical `TaskCanceledException`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577519/why-is-taskcanceledexception-thrown-and-does-not-always-breaks-into-the-debugger this should help you.

Answer (score 8):

> Under what circumstances will awaiting a cancelled task throw `OperationCanceledException` instead of the more typical `TaskCanceledException`?

This question is too broad. Even if one enumerated all scenarios where that happens today, it could change tomorrow.

Instead, I'll say this:

- `TaskCanceledException` is not "more typical". It was originally used in dynamic task-based parallelism, which has nothing to do with asynchronous programming.
- `OperationCanceledException` is a base class for `TaskCanceledException`. In your code, you should never catch `TaskCanceledException` (unless you *are* doing dynamic task-based parallelism **and** need to access `TaskCanceledException.Task`).

Just catch `OperationCanceledException` instead.

Comment: `TaskCanceledException` is generated by a cancelled task with no other exception to throw when `Wait()` is called and is the one provided by a `TaskCompletionSource`; regardless of the origin, it has a close association with task-based asynchronous programming.